# Redirect only certain requests to controller file using RewriteRule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I've created a controller file which handles redirecting users to the proper url, I want to direct certain traffic to this controller and not affect the rest. `http://website.com/shows.php?id=review-1` is an example of the url I want to send to the controller.

What I've concocted thus far is the following `RewriteRule` which causes a site-wide server 500 Server Error.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/shows\.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=review-[0-9]+(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /controller.php [QSA,L]
```

Removing the `-[0-9]+` from the `%{QUERY_STRING}` condition gets rid of the site-wide 500 Server Error, but doesn't work. The following `RewriteRule` that I'm trying to replace works just fine.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/shows\.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=review-1(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /review/1/super-baseball-2020/? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)?/?$ /shows.php?id=$1-$2 [QSA,L,NC]
```

The end result is that a user who goes to `http://www.website.com/shows.php?id=review-1` will end up at `http://www.website.com/controller.php?id=review-1` which will deal with handling the 301 redirect.

Comment: Rules work fine on my system. Try adding some parentheses. Couldn't you just use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=review- [NC]`? It will match a lot more than you want, but probably not any url you really use for something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why you're trying to make simple things into complex ones ;)

6 minutes to find+test. Here's what should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|(.)+&)(id=review-([0-9]+))($|&.*) [NC]
RewriteRule /shows.php /controller.php?%3 [QSA,L]
```

PS: Like Devin, I don't get/know why `(?:^|&)` works...

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Doesn't' look wrong, but I couldn't get the line

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=review-[0-9]+(?:&|$) [NC]
```

to compile in mod_rewrite until I took out the non-capturing indicators

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=review-[0-9]+(&|$) [NC]
```

seems to compile ok on my system, does that work for you?

Comment: I tried `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/shows\.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=review-1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /controller.php? [QSA,L]` and it still results in a 500 server error. (note, i changed it for only review-1 instead of a number range)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to ascertain what's causing the 500 error. I suspect the redirect is working, but the page you're being redirected to is failing.